# change on hidden field did not change on post

Tags: jquery

I am changing the value of a hidden field:

```
<input class="fruit_details" type="hidden" value="default_value" rel="fruits" name="data[fruits]">
```

Every change on the **select**, I assign the selected option text (not the value) to the hidden field:

```
$(selected_tr).find('td[rel=fruits_list] select').change(function() {
   $('.fruit_details input[rel=fruits]').val($(this).find(':selected').text());
   // ... so on
```

I did a **console.log** to see if the hidden field is updated, and yes it is:

```
console.log($('.fruit_details input[rel=fruits]').val());
```

After then the `$.post` is submitted, however, doing a backend check on PHP:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

shows the value of the hidden field is still its default value not the one selected from the `<select>`.

What am I missing? Is there any way to ensure the form gets the updated value of fields before submitting to post?

Comment: You should show your `$.post` command

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without more information, but:

Do you have multiple hidden fields being submitted? The reason behind using a class as opposed to an id e.g. `#fruit_details input[rel=fruits]` is typically because you have more than one, and having more than one input of the same name will give unexpected results.

Check the Network Tab of your developer tools to see what variables are actually being passed to your server and ensure that you're not getting the default value there. If you are getting the default value, then you know you have a problem with the JS. If it isn't, then you know something's getting muddled up on PHP's side.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are having more than one hidden(array), if not try passing the value directly to your php to see what is passed